# Is it against site rules for a sock-puppet to up-vote their own puppet's meta post?

Tags: discussion, voting, sock-puppets

We all know, and it should be obvious that sock-puppet accounts exist and in fact are allowed, as long as they don't perform actions that a single account couldn't do, such as up-voting itself (its partner) and such. But, does this also apply to meta posts, posts where there is no net reputation gain or loss from these posts?

My own thinking is that, yes, it should apply, since even if there is no reputation involved, it artificially changes the apparent approval of the meta post, and is an action that can't be performed by only one account.

The genesis of this question is from this recently deleted meta post, one that frankly surprised me to have received an up-vote:

[image: the question]

Comment: *it artificially changes the apparent approval of the meta post* --> well it's one uvpote so not a big change unless your friend aim to create multiple sock-puppet.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: no, it's not a big change, but it still can be an illegal change. Perhaps classified as a misdemeanor and not a felony

Comment: I found it rather humorous to upvote it.

Comment: @rene: aha, so *you're* the culprit. I'm good with that

Comment: Including that screen dump reduces this entire post to plain gossip.

Comment: If upvotes on meta mean 'yes' and downvotes mean 'no', then downvotes on that question are disturbing...

Comment: What happened to the rest of this question?

Comment: I deleted a portion of the question because I agreed with some answers that the information did not contribute to its intention, and in fact, much the opposite

Comment: Btw, in your case I had silently deleted the sock. No one had ever seen it. I think you overreacted this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely in violation of site policy (and in fact, network-wide policy) to use a sock-puppet account to upvote one's own content.

While it's true that there is no *reputation* to be gained from having one's Meta posts upvoted, there are other very measurable benefits. For example, with enough upvotes in a particular tag, one gets a gold tag-badge, which allows the holder to close posts on Meta as duplicates unilaterally. This is a very powerful privilege to have, and should absolutely not be gained through sock-puppetry. There may very well be other advantages to be gained from upvotes on Meta posts, changing the apparent approval of a post being one of the less obvious ones, as you pointed out.

The general principle is that one is not allowed to engage in *any* activity that one could not do with a single account, and that principle applies as much to Meta as to Main. Engaging in such behavior is not allowed, and the user may face suspensions, or other penalties if they are caught doing this.

The specific example that made you ask this question may or may not be due to a sock-puppet account; only CMs can actually know that for sure, and they usually only investigate cases where there is a reasonable suspicion of a pattern of such activity. In any case, if you *do* suspect that there is something untoward going on, you should raise a custom flag and explain the situation. I strongly suggest not discussing specific examples on Meta as it mostly leads to unproductive speculation about the situation.

Comment: "There may very well be other advantages to be gained from upvotes on Meta posts." Such as becoming eligible to stand for moderator election?

Comment: @francescalus Oh, really? I had no idea that there was any eligibililty criteria with regards to having upvoted content on Meta when it comes to standing for moderator elections. Could you share a link to that please?

Comment: The [Convention badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) has been a prerequisite for recent elections (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12)).

Comment: @francescalus Thank you very much for the link, that's very interesting. I should read up more on how elections work. I only started participating on SE actively (in terms of curation) after last year's elections were held, so I haven't really looked into any of those processes.

Answer (score -8):

It is not illegal in the sense that it probably does not break any written law in most jurisdictions. But it breaks the rules of the site, i.e. by doing that you violate the contract that you made with the company by registering here. The essence of the relevant U.S. law is that they can delete, suspend, and ban anybody for anything from their own site.

The essence of the relevant site rules is that anything is forbidden that you could not do with a single account. For example, not only voting on your own posts, but even supporting your own views in comments.

The typical punishment for this would be 1 month of suspension (+ destruction of your sock account), but mods have some freedom to forgive this (possible, particularly if you report your own mistake) or to give a harder punishment (very unlikely in your case).

Comment: The punishment varies and depends on the particular circumstances. In some cases, it might result only in a warning with no suspension at all.

Comment: @Dharman Yes, and probably this happened (will happen) now.

Comment: Technically speaking, I can support my own views in the comments.

Comment: @user253751 I agree whole-heartedly.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, but if you do it from another account, it would seem as if there would be others supporting you. This example was explicitly mentioned by a CM on the MSE, I can probably dig out a link if you wish to. Best if you avoid any interaction between your accounts.